# Calculate $\frac{a^8 + b^8}{a^8 - b^8} + \frac{a^8 - b^8}{a^8 + b^8}$ based on $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2 - b^2} + \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

> Given that $a$ and $b$ are distinct reals,
>
> calculate $\dfrac{a^8 + b^8}{a^8 - b^8} + \dfrac{a^8 - b^8}{a^8 + b^8}$ based on $\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2 - b^2} + \dfrac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Well... this problem is adapted from a recent competition... And I can't solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe adding and subtracting $a^4 b^4$ could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
$$x=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{a^{2}-b^{2}}+\frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}=2\frac{a^{4}+b^{4}}{a^{4}-b^{4}}.$$
Then
$$\frac{a^{4}+b^{4}}{a^{4}-b^{4}}+\frac{a^{4}-b^{4}}{a^{4}+b^{4}}=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2}{x}.$$
We can repeat this to get
$$\frac{a^{8}+b^{8}}{a^{8}-b^{8}}+\frac{a^{8}-b^{8}}{a^{8}+b^{8}}=\frac{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2}{x}}{2}+\frac{2}{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2}{x}}=\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4x}{x^{2}+4}.$$

Comment: You should finish your solution if you want to.

Comment: Have you been able to solve it yourself from this point?

Comment: Well, yes. The obvious is already there. But you could finish the solution for anyone who still doesn't get it.